# How to get source code difference between two projects

Tags: diff

I have created two java projects both have some common package structure and also same class. I want to compare these two projects and get each difference. Is there any software to get difference between two projects.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For windows, the best choice is [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). If you want it free - take [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). Under Unix, the best choice is [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) which is written in python, thus being also the only cross-platform alternative of the three.
All these tools support 2-way folder comparison which is what you seem to need here.

Comment: I used free trial version of BeyondCompare. Its really a good tool. Thanks kostja

Comment: Meld tool was very helpful for me. I was with a big problem between two projects, when the svn dont was unable to solve. Meld was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: WinMerge workes like a charm for me.

Comment: I just downloaded Meld and it's amazing! ty!

Comment: Is there any tool that can find similar types of logic or code blocks between two different projects?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a source code control system like [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or [git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) or [bazaar](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Download) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

Comment: The best choice IMO if you want to hit 2 birds with one stone. Version Control and getting the difference in code with every code push.

Answer (score 1):

There's [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). It's not free, but it is very good

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used WinMerge? you can use it to compare two folders and it will show you the differences between them.

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The interface is definitely dated, but I love [xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/doc/screenshots/xxdiff-snap-dirs2.html) for showing complex diffs and merge conflicts. Superb tool.

If you'd like to know what the differences are going forward, you might want to place both versions under a version control system like git, which can make finding differences (and moving changed code) *very* easy. But I'd have to want to do the same task again tomorrow to go this extra step. :)